# How to remove the Ubuntu Software Center Suggestions from the Dash

Tags: unity, software-center, unity-dash

I want to remove the Ubuntu Software Center Suggestions from the Dash in Ubuntu 12.10. How to do that?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Install dconf-tools `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools` then run `dconf-editor`. Go to desktop/unity/lenses/applications and uncheck display available apps.

[image]

Lets hope they make this easier in future versions.

Comment: In Ubuntu 13.04, I was able to simply type "dconf" in the Dash and the proper app appeared, no need to install the software first. Also, Dconf is also available in the Software Center if command line installs aren't your cup of tea.

Answer (score 1):

In **Ubuntu 14.04**, without any installations, just run

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Lenses remote-content-search 'none'
```