# How may I get rid off canonical addlens?

Tags: unity-dash, privacy

I did disable commercial entries in my privacy-settings. However, I still receive entries in my dashboard.

[image: launcher]

[image: launchsettings]

Comment: WHat you did was disable inclusion of online results, and your dash is indeed not showing online results (i.e. nothing from Amazon or other affiliate stores, no data from online scopes). What I see in your dashboard are: 1)

Comment: @roadmr Are what? It's stuff I don't want to buy.

Comment: @musher Not, it's obvisiously not from Amazon as roadmr wrote. Where does the Greedystuff come from?

Comment: @empedokles if you looked through that thread you'd see how to disable all of the canonical app store entries, as well.

Comment: I think that that is suggestions from the Ubuntu Software centre, as to what you may wish to install.

Comment: @empedokles (sorry, comment got posted before I finished it). these are results from software center. You can choose which sources are shown in your dash by clicking on "filter results", there you can choose which categories show in your dash, and from which sources. Give it a try and let me know. Also, please be more patient with volunteers trying to help you :)

Answer (score 8):

Uh, those are not Amazon results but Ubuntu Software Centre results. They are not live online results - but use data obtained by updating the `apt` database (which you would need to do for installing software anyway). No third party is involved. To disable it, see [How to remove the Ubuntu Software Center Suggestions from the Dash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/227950/how-to-remove-the-ubuntu-software-center-suggestions-from-the-dash).